# Where can I ask "Is there any way to see a deleted website other than the most obvious options?"

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to ask the following question:

> Is there any way to see a deleted website other than archive.org,
> archive.is, Google or Yandex cache? There was a [publication](http://vital.lib.tsu.ru/vital/access/manager/Repository/vital:12645) on
> the impact of one Syberian petrochemical plant. I summarized some of
> its points and included them in a piece I write for Russian
> Greenpeace. But now it's deleted and apparently not archived. It's
> like 1984! It freaks me out a bit. It's been "rectified" out of the
> internet. Or hasn't it?

Which site within the Stack Exchange network will take this question?

Comment: I've been kicked around SE with this question instead of being properly redirected, not fair. I've posted it here, because a user on SE Web Applications advised me so (https://ibb.co/fY70RKG)

Comment: The best we can do is change it into a site recommendation request, which I just did for you. I doubt it will get an answer that advices for a site in the network but we can wait a bit to see if that holds.

Comment: You were advised by the mod on web applications to ask for a site recommendation. The guidance is in the tag wiki: https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/site-recommendation/info

Comment: By the way, it was restored so it's less relevant now (but it was scary)